# Breeze deep query relationship navigation in TempHire Sample

Tags: breeze

I have another question here with the **Unit of Work (UoW)** and **Repository** pattern. So I like the repositories with UoW that the ***TempHire*** solution shows, very nice and I understand that. However, when you pass in a query that requests for an entity to be `.expand` or `.select` off of a parent, does the EFContextProvider call the repository for that action, or does it go straight to the `Context`. I looked into this a little, and I see that the `EFContextProvider` has it's own instance of the context.. This worries me because I have abstracted some things out using the repository pattern, however I don't think they are applied when doing these nested actions. Can anyone confirm this for me? If this is correct, Is there anyway to set this up so that is will go to my repository, which mimics the `DbContext`, for these nested calls?

Thanks Guys and Gals. Keep it Breezey

Answer (score 1):

The repositories as implemented in TempHire return the base IQueryable for any query. An .expand or .select gets simply appended to the base IQueryable before the query is executed. The EFContextProvider never calls the repository. The WebAPI controller calls on the repository to get the base IQueryable, which the repository gets from the DbContext inside of the EFContextProvider. The repository can further append to the IQueryable and so can the WebApi controller before the final IQueryable is returned to Breeze.NET which executes it. In other words all the logic you have in the repository that returns your base IQueryable will apply whether you execute the query as is or do an .expand or .select on it.

Comment: I guess my real question then is can I limit that IQueryable? I have rows that I want to restrict to certain users, I can do this easily with the repository pattern for the parent, However, an appended query  can potentially return restricted data. Any insight?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. You compose whatever base IQueryable you want with "Where" clauses that restrict the dataset. When a client adds .expand or .select it will be applied to the restricted dataset.

Comment: I should mention, though, that you can't restrict .expand. .expand gets passed through directly to Entity Framework, so the client could potentially request unrestricted data through one of your navigation paths. Many developers disallow .expand for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

EFContextProvider provides two things for breeze.js - metadata and SaveChanges. 
Queries go to the UoW repositories (please look at https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/TempHire/TempHire/Controllers/ResourceMgtController.cs).

Comment: Yes, I understand that they go to the repo for the inital request, I'm more interested in **deep queries**. Basically, I need a repository pattern for accessing children and parents as well